# refactoring Python to work witn snowpark pt1

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So, I have gone back to Python basics to make simple traditional Python code work with snowpark.

I am struggling to get any of the simple python code to work with snow

Pure Python

```
x_pos = 0

def move(x_pos, by_amount=9998):
    x_pos += by_amount
    return x_pos

final_x_pos = move(x_pos, 13)
print(final_x_pos)
```

Snowpark equivalent - attempt

```
x_pos = 0

def main(session: snowpark.Session, x_pos, by_amount=9998):
    x_pos += by_amount
    return x_pos

final_x_pos = main(x_pos, 13)
print(final_x_pos)

Handler has more arguments than expected. Function signature must have exactly one argument:
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
```

Another snowflake attempt

```
x_pos = 0

def move(x_pos, by_amount=9998):
    x_pos += by_amount
    return x_pos

final_x_pos = move(x_pos, 13)
print(final_x_pos)
def main(session: snowpark.Session, x_pos, by_amount):
    return(final_x_pos)

Handler has more arguments than expected. Function signature must have exactly one argument:
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
```

Another simple snowpark attempt that won't work

```
def add_num(num1,num2):
    return num1+num2
    result = add_num(10,20)
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    return (add_num)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant error messages for your code, plus any other relevant information. Just stating that something doesn’t work is not very helpful

Comment: Hi @NickW, I have updated the question with the error message

Comment: So what’s confusing you? I’m not sure how the error message could be any clearer?

Comment: Especially when you have the code working in the other question you raised today

Comment: I'd like to help, but I need more context of where/how this code will be deployed and used